# How to create an md5 hash of a string in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have an email and want to pull the corresponding image from gravatar.com

With ruby, it's easy:

```
    require 'Digest/md5'

    Digest::MD5.hexdigest("my string")
```

Since there is no `require` method in RubyMotion, how do I generate the hash from the email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is using the "NSData+MD5" cocoapod. Install it by adding this to your Rakefile (make sure you have `require 'motion-cocoapods'` up top):

```
app.pods do
  pod 'NSData+MD5Digest'
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
digest = NSData.MD5HexDigest("my string".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Comment: I'll try this after lunch, and mark you as the answer if it works. Thanks for the response!

Comment: This is how I got the pods set up: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/